# How to convert a string from a Prisma query into a Typescript enum

Tags: typescript, enums, prisma

I have a Prisma 4 model defined as:

```
model User {
  id     String  @id @default(uuid())
  status String? @db.VarChar(20)
}
```

and in Typescript I have an enum with string values:

```
enum Status {
  OK: `ok`,
  ERROR: `error`,
}
```

I can save data to this model:

```
await prisma.user.create({
  data: {
    status: Status.OK,
  }
});
```

This gets stored in the database in a `varChar(20)` field. However when I read this back the model is defined as a string so I'm getting Typescript errors saying that `Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'Status'`.

```
const user = await db.user.findFirst({
  where: {
    id: `uuidhere`,
  }
});

// Error here: Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'Status'
return <MyComponent status={user.status} />
```

Definition of `MyComponent`:

```
const MyComponent = ({ status }: { status: Status}) => {
  return <p>{status}</p>;
}
```

I know that a simple way would be to use the `as` keyword, however that defeats the purpose of type checking.

Is there a recommended practice to fix this, without, for example, having to call some function like this every place I use an enum?

```
// Don't want to have to call a function like this everywhere:
<MyComponent status={stringToStatus(model.status)} />
```

I was investigating if Prisma's middleware was valid option, but I believe you can only access the JSON of the result of the query.

Thanks!

Comment: "_when I read this back (currently using Prisma 4), the model is defined as a string_": Please update the question to include all relevant code in a [mre], ideally including a link to the example in the [TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&jsx=4&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/Q).

Comment: Added more supporting code.

Answer (score 0):

Not specific to Prisma:

When you receive a value from a function that you are confident is of a certain type, but the return type of the function does not describe that type, you can perform a runtime check to validate the type in order to inform the compiler of this scenario. The mechanism to do this is called a user-defined [type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates) — and you can combine this with an [assertion function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#assertion-functions) to throw an error if the validation fails... otherwise the compiler will know: from that point forward in your scope the value is of the type that you described. Here is an example using the code in your question:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&jsx=4&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true&ssl=37&ssc=3&pln=37&pc=68#code/KYOwrgtgBAygLgQzmAzlA3gKClA8gaSgF4oByAewGtSAabKAUQCUncnizgAnL8r2zAF9MmOAE8ADsCgBVFNw5YcASwAmALigo4XZSADmAbnrakqTfDMpjg45gBmYEAGM4y8iCjKUchQAoANwQAGzBgTSdKEHIAdxAASk0g0OlvWXkuDHouYGQuTz96HHEpcnsoZLDiIhIKACMAK2BXUiKoADJ2qBLgMqhAkKqENAQQMXiAfgA6NWra7V0DVpwcTqgAbUtkFCnmViYaWERtqYIAXRmXUNVgFD8BlKhhp7HJqdNt+Pp4mxFHFzcHieKAycH6wAAHhIuBEQFFYiBDhAUPoJpoFnp9IlgaC0JDoVkVOU-ABCfFceLdAAWvBiUBAwDpDB4fD8yKxv0wAHouelwiIbs5gggclBnB5tFBVHVNOgoKhuLKoPY9KoAGLKLjaTQPMKw+FxSlEAB8UAACrwIN5gAAeSLROKmwRQWwiPzDMQufpG01KMUSsEKzIkBAxBDKMHSqZBqYqkDqzXaPx+nAxKnccKElYqDRQAAGYDAanTOTzdGzwhwgh+IhwQeMPIAehNazjuHA-N5fFw-EH4odSAAVdMVQbSaHkAJqYCqLxoaJgvo9KAAIm7K9INfo9e5XObrZjH1QxmzUCbLerfhrQA)

```ts
// Your enum:
enum Status {
  OK = 'ok',
  ERROR = 'error',
}

// Your User type:
type User = {
  id: string;
  status: Status;
};

// A type guard for narrowing a value to your User type
function isUser (value: unknown): value is User {
  return (
    typeof value === 'object'
    && typeof (value as any)?.id === 'string'
    && [Status.ERROR, Status.OK].includes((value as any)?.status)
  );
}

// A generic assertion function
function assert (expr: unknown, msg?: string): asserts expr {
  if (!expr) throw new Error(msg);
}
```

Using them in the async context where you retrieve the user from your database:

```ts
  const user = await db.user.findFirst({
    where: {
      id: `uuidhere`,
    }
  });

  user;
//^? const user: unknown

  // If an error is not thrown here, then afterward in this scope,
  // the compiler will know that `user` is of type `User`:
  assert(isUser(user), 'The value provided is not of type "User"');

  user;
//^? const user: User

  user.status;
     //^? (property) status: Status

  // Set the user to some React state at this point, etc.
```